# How to test split char test to search?

Tags: c#, string, linq, split, testcase

I'm trying to create select search to to find people by first name or last name but when the user type search for name I have couple of cases

1. fullName String ex"john"
2. fullName contains split char "."  ex:john.dow
3. fullName contains split char "_" ex:john_dow
4. fullName contains split char " " ex:john dow

My problem is if always run the first case my Question how can I make my code run the right case

C#

```
using System;

namespace separatefullnamestring
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string query = "fulname.kkkkk";


//          var result  = from tableA in ContextDB.tblA
//              join tableB in ContextDB.tblb tableA. ID equals tableB.ID
//              select tableA;
//

            //String.isNullOrEmpty(query)
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (query)) {
                Console.WriteLine ("fullname ");
                //result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(query) || p.LastName.containe(query));

            } else // if full name contine containe . firstName.LastName
                if (query.Contains (".")) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Contains .");
//                  var names = fullName.Split ('.');
//                  string fName = names[0];
//                  string lName = names[1];
//                  result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(fName) || p.LastName.containe(lName));

            } else   // if full name contine containe _ firstName_LastName
                    if (query.Contains ("_")) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Contains .");
//                      var names = fullName.Split ('_');
//                      string fName = names[0];
//                      string lName = names[1];
//                      result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(fName) || p.LastName.containe(lName));

            } else   // if full name contine containe space firstName_LastName
                        if (query.Contains (" ")) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Contains ");
                //var names = fullName.Split ('_');
                //string fName = names[0];
                //string lName = names[1];
                //result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(fName) || p.LastName.containe(lName));

            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ninjas always use RegExes... So get one and split on word boundary...

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+regex+word+boundary or add "split" to get code samples - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20regex%20split%20word%20boundary ... Or simply split on non-letters - `Regex.Split("a,b,c", @"[^a-z]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues with the code.

1. The first conditional "!String.IsNullOrEmpty (query)" would force any non-null or empty query value to stop processing at this time.  *Solution:* Increased the scope of the conditional, so if the case is true, the application would end.
2. The conditional statement for "else if (query.Contains ("_"))" Console.Writeline displays the exact same text as the conditional above it, thus making debugging a little difficult because you were unsure which statement you were on. *Solution:* Corrected the text in the Writeline statement.

**Updated code:**

```
string query = "fulname_kkkkk";

// var result  = from tableA in ContextDB.tblA
//              join tableB in ContextDB.tblb tableA. ID equals tableB.ID
//              select tableA;
//
//String.isNullOrEmpty(query)
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (query)) {
    if (query.Contains (".")) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Contains .");
//                  var names = fullName.Split ('.');
//                  string fName = names[0];
//                  string lName = names[1];
//                  result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(fName) || p.LastName.containe(lName));

    } else if (query.Contains ("_")) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Contains _");
//                      var names = fullName.Split ('_');
//                      string fName = names[0];
//                      string lName = names[1];
//                      result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(fName) || p.LastName.containe(lName));
    } else if (query.Contains (" ")) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Contains ");
                //var names = fullName.Split ('_');
                //string fName = names[0];
                //string lName = names[1];
                //result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(fName) || p.LastName.containe(lName));
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine ("fullname ");
        //result = result.where(p => p.FirstName.containe(query) || p.LastName.containe(query));
    }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting program");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
string str = "john_dow";

string[] names = Regex.Split(str, @"\p{P}|\s");
```